# train a spam classiﬁer using support vector machines

Tags: r

In this exercise you will train a spam classiﬁer using support vector machines. We will use the spam dataset which comes with the {kernlab} package. First, we will split the spam data randomly into two halves: one half we will use as the training data, the other half we will use as the test data. The target variable is type which is a binary class spam and nospam.

0. Look at the help page for the dataset to ﬁnd out what the diﬀerent columns mean (hint:

?spam).

1. Fit a support vector classiﬁer using svm() on the training data. type is the target and all other variables can be used as predictors (hint: you can use the . notation which automatically includes all columns of the data.frame as predictors except the target variable).
2. Predict spam/nonspam classes for the data in the test dataset. How does the predicted classiﬁcation compare with the true classes? What is the classiﬁcation error?
3. Can you improve the classiﬁcation accuracy? (Hint: Start by exploring diﬀerent settings for the cost attribute and using diﬀerent predictors.)
4. How easy is it to interpret the classiﬁcation performed using svm? Compare the interpretability of the svm model to that of a regression model (e.g., like the one from the exercises above).

I started with this code:

```r
# install.packages("kernlab") 
library(e1071) 
library(kernlab) 
data(spam) 
dim(spam) 
head(spam)
set.seed(02115)
sample <- sample( c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(spam), replace=TRUE) 
train <- spam[sample,] 
test <- spam[!sample,]
```

**What should I do next?**

Comment: You can use other implementations on the web as reference . One is [here](http://thinktostart.com/build-a-spam-filter-with-r/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. You can use `svm()` and `glm()` to test the algorithms and evaluate the performance. Here the code.

```
library(e1071) 
library(kernlab) 
data(spam) 
set.seed(02115)
sample <- sample( c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(spam), replace=TRUE) 
train <- spam[sample,] 
test <- spam[!sample,]
#Code for svm
fitsvm <- svm(type~.,type='C-classification',kernel='linear',data = train)
predssvm <- predict(fitsvm, test)
predictedclasssvm <- predssvm
trueclasssvm <- test$type
#Code for glm
fitglm <- glm(type~.,family = 'binomial',data=train)
predsglm <- predict(fitglm, test,type='link')
predictedclassglm <- predsglm
predictedclassglm <- ifelse(predictedclassglm>=0.5,'spam','nonspam')
trueclassglm <- as.character(test$type)
```

StatML models are trained on train set and must be tested on test set. In the case of `glm()` you have to define a cut-off point (commonly defined as 0.5). With that you can compute the accuracy of models:

```
#Accuracy svm
sum(predictedclasssvm == trueclasssvm)/length(predictedclasssvm)
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.9274989
```

And for GLM:

```
#Accuracy glm
sum(predictedclassglm == trueclassglm)/length(predictedclassglm)
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.9176319
```

SVM shows better performance in the task spam/nonspam but GLM is also good. You can try other kernel for SVM and an improvement for boosting models can be scaling all numeric variables.